# .net Core 2 problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I had to rebuild my main work station. Before the rebuild, all worked fine. After the rebuild, regular .net apps build with no issues. However, .net core fails on an existing project and if I create a new web or console project I get the same errors. Two main errors received...

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> NU1202: Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools 2.0.1
>   is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0).
>   Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools 2.0.1 does not
>   support any target frameworks.

I tried it in both the regular (15.5.2) version and preview (15.6.p Preview 1.1) version.

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core 2.0. SDK?

Comment: Using visual studio 2017?

Comment: @CaiusJard `15.5.2` means `Visual Studio 2017 Update 5.2`. VS 2017 is version `15.X`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I always thought SDK installed as part of VS installation as long as .Net core was selected during setup ... is that not the case anymore ?

Comment: @MuqeetKhan I believe that 15.5 installs the latest version of the SDK during setup, yeah. I don't think it used to though.

Comment: Two questions: which version of the .NET Core SDK is installed on your system? (run the following command in your terminal `dotnet --version`) And what happens if you manually build the app in the terminal? ( try `dotnet restore` then `dotnet build` and let us know what errors you get there). My thinking here is that either you have v1.x of the SDK installed, or Visual Studio is unable to do a package restore for some reason

Comment: dotnet --version = 2.1.2

dotnet restore...
D:\DotNetRazor\yyyZLib\yyyZLib.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.CSharp 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [D:\DotNetRazor\CondoAdminNet\CondoAdminNet.sln]

 dotnet build... 173 warnings and 240 errors 

It is almost like 2.12 isn't compatible with 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Finally had time to get back to the problem. I stripped the computer, reinstalled Windows and before anything else I installed .Net Core 2.0. After installing SQL and VS, all worked. If you ever have to redo your computer, you may want to install Core 2.0, before installing VS.